# Как построить интервальную оценку для среднего по выборке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, matplotlib, график

Eсть [таблица в эксель](https://yadi.sk/i/3teWjGq3OZqxLA). Она содержит следующие столбцы: название города, год, максимальное число заболевших за год, маркер Э, общее число заболевших, номер недели и относительную заболеваемость.

Для каждого года и города нужно построить интервальную оценку для среднего по выборке. Например в Архангельске выборка состоит из 27 значений. В результате  получаем один столбец с усами с помощью matplotlib как в [этом примере](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/barchart_demo.html).

Comment: Приведите нужную информацию в самом вопросе, потому что ссылки могут стать недействительными в будущем

Comment: какой столбец вы подразумеваете, говоря "`среднее по выборке`" ?

Comment: последний с относительной заболеваемостью

Comment: на графике все сольется, т.к. слишком много городов...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Скорее всего вам не подойдет данный вид визуализации:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\download\3-6.xlsx')
sns.barplot(x='cld_year', y='относительная заболеваемость', hue='town_name', data=df)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

приблизительно такая же "каша" получается если чертить линейные графики:

```
df.pivot_table(index='cld_year', columns='town_name', values='относительная заболеваемость', aggfunc='mean').plot(figsize=(14, 8))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно попробовать воспользоваться `boxplot`:

```
(df.pivot_table(columns='town_name', index='cld_year', 
                values='относительная заболеваемость', aggfunc='mean', fill_value=0)
   .plot.box(rot=90, figsize=(16,10)))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно ли упорядочить их слева направо по возрастанию?

Comment: @Анна, по возрастанию чего?

Comment: значений последнего столбика в таблице